# Looking for multiple file uploader using Express+Node

Tags: node.js, express, npm, blueimp

I am working in one Node Application. My requirement is to upload multiple Image Files.

I want [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) type of module.

I find also this [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blueimp-file-upload-expressjs) but it is not working.

Is any one know any other module for implementing multiple file uploader just like blueimp.

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: I want file uploader like blueimp, which provided view of uploaded image and also delete at the same time.